# Google authentication with Angular2 and ASP.NET core Web API app

Tags: google-api, google-signin

I'm creating an web application in Angular2 and i'd like to use Google for the user to login and use the application. Basically, once the user is logged in with Google, he will navigate in the site and make some AJAX call via Angular to the ASP.NET Core Web API.

In my mind, I though that all these calls should contain a JWT (issued by Google) and the ASP.NET Core Web Api would validate the token and then process the request if the token is valid. Simple enough... However, I'm struggling to find out how this could be achieved. All I found is posts talking about how to login via Google in order to use Google APIs. In my case, I don't need any Google API but the login one.

So far, I have this:

```
export class GoogleAuthenticationService {
    private auth: any;

    constructor(private userService: UserService) {

    }

    public bindLoginButton(element: any) {
        this.ensureApiIsLoaded().then(() => {
            this.auth.attachClickHandler(element, {}, (user) => {
                let profile = user.getBasicProfile();

                this.userService.set(profile.getName(), profile.getEmail(), user.getAuthResponse().id_token, AuthenticationType.Google);
            });
        });
    }

    // TODO: Better type definition of the promise
    private ensureApiIsLoaded() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            gapi.load('auth2', () => {
                this.auth = gapi.auth2.init({
                    client_id: "CLIENT_ID",
                    cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
                    scope: 'profile email'
                });

                resolve();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Basically, I'm just initializing "gapi" with my client ID, then I define some properties in the "UserService". This works pretty well. Moreover, I'm using the value returned by `user.getAuthResponse().id_token` for every call to my web service (I did this following [this article](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth)). The next step was to try and validate the token in C# (like the sample in Java) but I didn't find any valid resources talking about that and the class used in the Java code does not exists in C#...

Is it that complicated or am I just on the wrong path and this is totally not how the web application is supposed to work. Could someone give me some pointers about this scenario that is, according to me, quite common.

Comment: Hi, I'm struggling now with the same thing. Could you get anywhere? I'm reading somethings about needing to use ExternalCookies in your web api but most of that is for framework - not core